# Google Geocoding API Not Returning adminstrative area level 2

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

We're using the Google Geocoding API to populate the County field in a database of store locations. The API returns a location's County in the "administrative_area_level_3" node of the result set.

An example of the result set we'd expect is:

```
    "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1100",
               "short_name" : "1100",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Front Street",
               "short_name" : "Front St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Morgan City",
               "short_name" : "Morgan City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "6",
               "short_name" : "6",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "St. Mary County",
               "short_name" : "St Mary County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Louisiana",
               "short_name" : "LA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "70380",
               "short_name" : "70380",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1100 Front St, Morgan City, LA 70380, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 29.7015251,
                  "lng" : -91.21346009999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.701518,
                  "lng" : -91.213477
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 29.701518,
               "lng" : -91.213477
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 29.7028705302915,
                  "lng" : -91.21211956970848
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.7001725697085,
                  "lng" : -91.2148175302915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "EikxMTAwIEZyb250IFN0LCBNb3JnYW4gQ2l0eSwgTEEgNzAzODAsIFVTQQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
```

Ocassionally, the API returns a result set that does not contain the administrative_area_level_3 node. For example:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "48th Street",
           "short_name" : "48th St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Newport News",
           "short_name" : "Newport News",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Virginia",
           "short_name" : "VA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "48th St, Newport News, VA, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.004314,
              "lng" : -76.40833950000001
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 36.992475,
              "lng" : -76.439454
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 36.9986291,
           "lng" : -76.4239863
        },
        "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.004314,
              "lng" : -76.40833950000001
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 36.992475,
              "lng" : -76.439454
           }
        }
     },
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "ChIJf4pmrRCduokR6tpCG9H5Wbg",
     "types" : [ "route" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "2306",
           "short_name" : "2306",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "48th Street",
           "short_name" : "48th St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Briarfield",
           "short_name" : "Briarfield",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hampton",
           "short_name" : "Hampton",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Virginia",
           "short_name" : "VA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "23661",
           "short_name" : "23661",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "2306 48th St, Hampton, VA 23661, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.004314,
           "lng" : -76.40833950000001
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.0056629802915,
              "lng" : -76.40699051970851
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.0029650197085,
              "lng" : -76.40968848029152
           }
        }
     },
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "ChIJGTG5l9-cuokRmnDAATl0HQI",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
```

],
   "status" : "OK"
}

We did some research on these addresses, and found that the addresses are correct (no typos). So we're not sure why the API isn't returning the administrative area level 3 value.

Does anyone know why the API doesn't return this node for some of the locations?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably some kind of data issue. I can suggest filing an issue in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188871) of Maps APIs.

Comment: Thank you! I reviewed the Public Issue Tracker and found a similar issue has already been reported.. It appears that it is not an issue with the Google Geocoding API, but rather an issue with the underlying Google Maps Data. According to the Issue Tracker, there are some addresses for which Google Maps does not have a County.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827559

Thanks for your help @xomena !